# problems with Xcode 10 on existing project with server-side Swift (Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred)

Tags: swift, server-side, xcode10

Does anybody face the same problem with Xcode 10 on an existing server-side Swift project that builds just fine with Xcode10 n-1?
I'm facing a Swift Compile error (Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred) in the Strand.switch file in Dependencies -> Core 1.1.2 -> Core chain.
I've created the project some time ago from the command line (swift package init --type executable) and generated an Xcode project from it.

I could use Xcode to further develop the project, but since the upgrade, it throws me this error.  I can, however, compile and run it from the command line (swift build and .build/debug/projName)

I've Cleaned the project, I've updated the packages (swift package update), regenerated the xcode project (swift package generate-xcodeproj) and set the version of swift back to 4.1.2 with swiftenv in the project directory.
Still, Xcode throws me that error.

Any ideas

Comment: This is a very specific set of circumstances that I can't relate to, but the "Generic parameter 'T' could not be in inferred" and related generic errors has caused me grief in Xcode 10.